# Question about SQL Server database design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a database table named Student that stores student's information, however when a student graduates, their info is no longer stored in Student table anymore, but I still want to stored that info for further use. So my best method is push that info into another table named GraduatedStudent (Student table is not allowed to stored graduated student info)

I also have a table named StudentsPayment that uses a foreign key (Student ID) of student table. When I push Graduated Student away from student table, the StudentsPayment get an error that it can't find that student ID in the Student table anymore. I can't figure out anyway in design to solve this problem so please help.

Comment: What about just adding a flag to the table for IsGraduated (or similar)  you keep them in the Student table but with the flag.  Then if you need any graduate info to tie to the student table create graduate info table to hold any extra info not contained in student table.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you don't have your foreign keys set up if you're getting an error about that a row can't be found; as you wouldn't have been able to "move" that student (`INSERT` them into a different table and `DELETE` from the from original) if they did.

Comment: _Student table is not allowed to stored graduated student info_ Why? Defend your approach, don't try to "work around" it.

Comment: yes i have thoght that to, in the student table there is a foreign key call IsInRoom stored room ID of Room table, when i tick that is graduate flag, the info of that room still there (that graduate student not suppose to in that room because.. he graduated) but some how i still want to know what room he used

Comment: And "students" come and go all the time. A student might not complete their degree. Fees should likely be attached to a person - regardless of that person's current (or past) relationship to the "school". I think you need to analyze and study your requirements more thoroughly.

Comment: To @SMor's point, the flag you want is `IsCurrent`. Otherwise you'll go down the rabbit hole of `IsGraduated`, `IsTransferred`, `IsADropOut`,`IsOnSabbatical`,`IsJustMissing`, and you'll never be done with your design.

Comment: If you are using SQLServer from 2016 onwards, then a good option for this would be temporal tables - you can store the student history with start and end dates.

Answer (score 1):

You, essentially, have 2 options

1. Mirror all of the tables foreign keyed to `Student` for the `GraduatedStudent` table. So you end up with a mirror of `StudentPayment` as `GraduatedStudentPayment` and when you move a student you must also move all of their payments (and any other relationships)
2. Add a flag to `Student` table to say `IsGraduated` (or, even better the opposite `IsActive`) and you're done. You can always use views to replicate the functionality of `CurrentStudent` and `GraduatedStudent` if thats what you want to do.

I know which option I would choose. No points for guessing which!

---

Edited to add some points about a comment:

> in the student table there is a foreign key call IsInRoom stored room ID of Room table, when i tick that is graduate flag, the info of that room still there (that graduate student not suppose to in that room because.. he graduated) but some how i still want to know what room he used

This is easily solveable. You introduce a `RoomHistory` table and make the `IsInRoom` nullable. When a student graduates you null their current `IsInRoom` and add a record to the `RoomHistory` table. This might be useful also to srtore a complete history when/if a student moves rooms. You can add some extra columns to store when they started and stopped using a particular room.

Comment: that mean you have to use query ? in edit mode this could lead to data conflict, this is a fault point that i try to solve in design

Comment: @Valkyrine I don't understand the question - but in general data integrity can be ensured using transactions for atomic work

Comment: some one could accidentally add a record to RoomHistory although that stundent have not Graduated yet

Comment: @Valkyrine you need to look into databases a little more. All these sort of problems are easily solvable at the database level. Look up "check constraints" for starters

Comment: ah yes, i totally forgot about it, thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You could have a table, lets call it StudentInformations, that store student infos wether they have graduated or not. Then you could access it with the Student, GraduatedStudent and StudentsPayment.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have stated two mutually exclusive requirements (1) Student table is not allowed to stored graduated student info, and (2) the student id in the student payments table must exist in the students table. You can relax the first requirement and then, as the previous commentator suggested, add a "Graduated" flag to the student table. Alternatively, you could create a new table, maybe call it  Person, then primary key of which (person id) then becomes the foreign key in both the student and student loan tables.